# Magento - checkout progress under each step

Tags: magento

Instead of having a progress summary on a side bar, is it possible to break up progress data and put them under each step?

For example in bigcartel's site, after filling out a section, data is displayed instead of the form. Please note the section above "Shipping":

[image: Bigcartels form]

Is it something that is easily done or would it require altering core code?

Comment: Nothing is easily done in Magento.  And yes, moving around data on the screen requires altering code.

Answer (score 0):

The checkout is done via AJAX and the html contents for each step is returned as you progress from step to step. You will need to probably extend the checkout controller and get it to also return the previous step html data (i.e. what you want it to display without the textboxes) and extend the checkout javascript classes to update the page with the returned html from the ajax request. Personally I would not do this, altering the checkout from the core is no easy task and if you don't know what your doing it could cost you all your sales! It seems to me that a one page checkout module might be more suited to your needs. There are many existing ones already available.